# Java Stream API: Throwing custom exception for empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, java-stream

I have the following service method:

```
public void create(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
      List<Employee> employees = CsvHelper.csvToEmployees(file.getInputStream()).stream()
              .map(EmployeeRequestMapper::mapToEntity)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
     
      // Can I use Stream and throw exception if employees is empty
      if (employees.isEmpty()) {
          throw new NoSuchElementFoundException(NOT_CONTAINS_EMPLOYEE);
      }

      employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
}
```

Here I read CSV file and if there is no record, throw my custom `NoSuchElementFoundException` exception.

However, **regarding to if block**, I am not sure if there is a proper way using Java Stream as I use in the following example:

```
public EmployeeDto findByEmail(String email) {
    return employeeRepository.findByEmail(email)
            .map(EmployeeDto::new)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException(NO_ITEM_FOUND));
}
```

So, can I apply similar one to the `create()` method?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What is the problem with the current approach of using `...orElseThrow(...)`? We normally use `Stream`s if we have multiple entries, but `findByEmail(...)` seems to return an `Optional` (i.e. 0 or 1 entries), so this is the "correct" approach.

Comment: I am not asking `findByEmail` method, it is ok of course. I am asking `create` method.

Comment: @Turing85 Why vote down?

Comment: No. Your clarification got the problem across. There is, however, one point unclear: are we actually talking about a `null`-value for the list, or an empty list? If we are talking about a `null` value, where can it occur? Can the parameter itself be `null`, or can the value of `CsvHelper.csvToEmployees` be null? For `null` value, the default approach is using `Optional.ofNullable(...).orElseThrow(...)`. There is -as far as I know, no possibility to check if a `Stream` is empty without consuming it. So the depature of converting it to a `List` and checking that seems like a plausible solution.

Comment: @Turing85 Regarding to null, you are right I meant "Empty" and corrected comment, sorry.  As it is a list, when there is no record it will return null list and I want to handle this situation. But I am not sure if there is an elegant solution instead of using if block. Any idea?

Comment: Wrap it in `Optional.ofNullable(...).orElseThrow(...)...`.

Comment: Thanks, but as it is List, I need to check empty instead of null. I tried to be sure, but unfortunately not working. Any idea for this kind of situations using Java Stream?

Comment: I am trying `Optional.empty(employees).orElseThrow(() ->  new NoSuchElementFoundException(NO_RECORD));`

Comment: But `empty()` does not expect any parameter :(

Comment: Also tried `employees.isEmpty().orElseThrow(() ->  new NoSuchElementFoundException(NO_RECORD));`, not working

Comment: Some people used like me, some others suggest like this (adding filter) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869805/java-8-throw-exception-if-stream-returns-no-results

Comment: Your code is just fine the way it stands. I see no reasonable way to change it to throw the exception from within a stream pipeline.

Comment: @OleV.V. You right, I have seen that after my search. But as I have not experience for this situations, just wanted to be sure by getting some suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks a lot to you also for your useful helps

Comment: Thanks, hans. I am not going to post an answer, so if you think you’ve got your question answered, in half or in full, consider posting your own answer to it.

Comment: If you _really_ want to use Stream/Optional to throw the exception, you can do this: `Optional.of(employees).filter(e -> !e.isEmpty()).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException())`. But this is beating around the bush, and your use of an if statement is better.

Comment: @DBear You are right, then I will continue to use current approach. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, which will be applied after the result is collected on the list and it will check if the result list is empty and if that is the case it will throw the exception

```
    public void create(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
  List<Employee> employees = CsvHelper.csvToEmployees(file.getInputStream()).stream()
          .map(EmployeeRequestMapper::mapToEntity)
          .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), result -> {
            if (result.isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementFoundException(NOT_CONTAINS_EMPLOYEE);
            return result;
           })); 
 employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
 }
```